# How to make my neural networks designs more robust

Tags: backpropagation, hyperparameter-optimization, hyper-parameters, resource-request

Whenever, I design a neural network to solve a novel problem (requires a novel loss function i.e. not image classification) it always ends up being hypersensitive to batch size and learning rate.

Andrej Karpathy [compared](https://youtu.be/P6sfmUTpUmc?t=5650) training neural networks to balancing a pencil on your figure. It seams things like image classification are only workable because people have stumbled on to magic tricks like batch norm, skip connections, relu. And as you venture away from image classification, machine learning returns to a hypersensitive balancing act.

Andrej Karpathy [recomends](https://youtu.be/q8SA3rM6ckI?t=59) understanding backprop/autograd. I imagine reducing a batch of losses by mean rather than sum, will help make the gradients more invariant to the batch size resulting in the neural net being more robust to choices of the learning rate. Currently, my loss function involves calculating a covariance matrix and probably dividing by $n^2$ would help with the hypersensitivity.

I'm wanting to know if there are any references of how you can use your understanding on backprop to design neural networks that are more robust (less hypersensitive) to arbitrary choices of hyperparameters.

Is the job of machine learning engineers to balance hypersensitive hyperparameters (i.e. find lucky choices) or is the job to design networks that are robust to arbitrary choices?

It seems like most people just use exactly what architectures the gods at google research have handed to them (i.e. transformers haven't really changed) rather than taking a more humanistic approach of making these problems more tractable.